# Cannot Share host directory with VirtualBox Guest Mint 16 64 bit

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

**Problem**
When attempting to mount a shared directory from Linux Mint 16 VirtualBox guest OS, I receive the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on hostshare,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

My mount command is sudo mount -t vboxsf hostshare ~/host

dmesg | tail reveals: 'sf_read_super_aux err=-22'

**Environment**
 - Host OS: Windows 7 64 bit
 - Guest OS: Linux Mint 64 bit (Mate)
 - VirtualBox 4.3.10
 - VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.3.10
 - Shared directory defined in VirtualBox as 'hostshare' with Make Permanent checked
 - ~/host is defined on the guest OS file system

**What I have tried**
I can mount this directory from other VirtualBox guests, including Mint 15 32 bit.
I reinstalled guest additions on Mint 16 and from what I can see, it is running. I have rebooted the host OS, VirtualBox and the Guest OS several times.
I renamed the shared folder to various silly things to no avail.
Changed VirtualBox network from NAT to Bridged Adaptor. 
Other Guest Additions features (Shared Clipboard, Drag'n'Drop) work properly.

Comment: I finally fixed it but I'm too new to post the answer :(. The symlink for mount.vboxsf was broken. Here's what I ran to correct it:

cd /sbin
sudo rm mount.vboxsf
sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf

Hope this is of use to someone else!

Comment: Thank you so much for your discovery. I was going nuts. I wonder how you guessed that the problem was a broken symlink, given that the error message is so vague. I am on Debian wheezy 7.4 32-bit. The correct link in my case was `ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf`. Please post it as a solution as soon as you have enough rep so I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 8):

I confirm your solution. I'm using a debian 7 amd64 guest on a windows 7 64-bits.
I updated virtualbox from 4.3.8 to 4.3.10.
The following symlink: /sbin/mount.vboxsf points to /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf whereas the real path to mount.vboxsf is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf.

This issue seems to be [fixed](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12879) in virtualbox subversion repository. Thus, it should be fixed in next version.

Comment: In the meantime a workaround could be:
`sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf /sbin/mount.vboxsf`

Comment: Solution worked great, but I can't figure out for the life of me why this "broke" all of a sudden. I'm not doing any automatic updating.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. and the solution of the topic starter almost worked for me, but in Lubuntu 13 instead of

```
ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf
```

I used

```
ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf
```

Answer (score 1):

For Debian:

There is a symbolic link in `/sbin` folder, file `mount.vboxsf`, which is linked wrong. 
The right link is `mount.vboxsf` -> `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-xxxxx/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/mount.vboxsf`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a simblic link in /usr/lib64 which points to folder:

> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions/

It works in my Kubuntu 14.04 guest on a Windons 7 host